# C#.net best way to queue emails with attachments for sending

Tags: c#, .net, email, message-queue

I am looking into a way to more securely send emails from our application.

We are currently sending emails directly to an IIS SMTP server but are looking at ways to more securely deliver emails if the server goes down, restarts etc.

I was thinking a way to implement this would be to store the emails (with attachments) in a queue to be process by a separate process, or store the emails in the database to be then processed.

I was wanting to get some advice and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a likewise case. We solved it by storing the emails in a database that keeps fault and retry status. We're using [FreeSMTP](http://www.quiksoft.com/freesmtp/) to send the actual messages. Quicksoft also has a all-out product that handles errors itself and keeps its own message database if that is what you're looking for (not so free though ;-))